# Is Kafka's protocol for exchange of group related metadata peer-to-peer?

Tags: apache-kafka, client, protocols, p2p

My project is using Kafaka 0.10.1.0, and I was pawing through the source trying to learn a bit.

I had a question about Kafka's protocol for the exchange of group related metadata, is this a peer-to-peer
type protocol wherein the Coordinator for a given consumer group runs on client machines?

The documentation for org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator mentions
one step in the protocol is:

```
   <li>Group/Leader Selection: The coordinator select the members of the group and chooses one member
       as the leader.</li>
```

So, it seems the group leader logic runs on the client side. I guess this would be good for scalability, offloading
from the broker, but I wanted to confirm with a Kafa expert that I came to the correct conclusion.  Thanks !

Comment: Why use such an old version of Kafka?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the brokers is a coordinator for the cluster, and the first consumer client to join a group becomes *group coordinator*.

By definition of having a single coordinator, it is leader-follower protocol, not p2p, in which each node is typically equal

Comment: just one other question, to confirm the leader (coordinator) is a client machine... so it is definitely not a 'client server' type protocol.  My guess is one of the strengths of these types of protocols is scalability.. in that the server (brokers) are not the bottleneck. Close ?   /thanks again for educating me on this.

Comment: The coordinator is one of the brokers https://medium.com/streamthoughts/apache-kafka-rebalance-protocol-or-the-magic-behind-your-streams-applications-e94baf68e4f2

Comment: @samlaf The question wasn't about bitcoin

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you meant by "technically bitcoin...." then, when that wasn't part of this topic. I also said "typically" in my answer, which implies there are exceptions